# If my question is off topic and should be on Super User, why not transfer it?

Tags: discussion

My question about running a VOIP service was closed for being off topic and the moderator said it should be on Super User. Why not transfer it to Super User instead of closing it then? Goofy I say.

Now it will damage my chances of asking future questions, and I will have to copy it to Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moderators here have discussed with other moderators, including on Super User. I would need to search Super User to see if it is a duplicate, then ask the moderators there if it is a question they will accept. I just do not have the time to do all your work for a person who fails to read the parameters for asking a question here.

Comment: I thought the stuff I was using was used by professionals. Also how do professionals connect to the PSTN if they don’t use an FXO Gateway, hmm? You don’t have to be an a-hole, alright. Somehow moderators have found the time to transfer one of my questions in the past. Stack exchange is so picky, at least it seems for me

Comment: Also, if you even have to ask the Super User moderators to see if that question can be asked on Super User, then how am I ever supposed to figure out if I can ask it on there? Ask if I can ask my question? I’m asking on Quora instead if Stack Exchange has to be this way

Comment: Bro has to be acoustic

Answer (score 0):

As Ron already answered, there's a lot involved in moving a question between sites. Mods of one site may not know the etiquette and on-topic rules of other sites. (eg, most other mods don't know NE's rules.) It is infinitely easier for the user to simply (re)post their question on a different part of SE. It's also SE practice to not move questions without answers.

I've never understood why people get so upset, and waste so much energy complaining about their question being closed and referred elsewhere when it takes seconds to do as asked, post elsewhere, and get an answer there in hours, or minutes; but no, they have to waste days arguing with mods rather than getting their answers.